# C program. Upper or Lower... bit masking and while loop

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a program that will let the user input as many
characters as they want. The program will then check if the characters are upper case or lower case. If the program detects a lower case letter in the input stream the program will print out the letter in char type and its hex number. When it encounters EOF and all of the letters entered are upper case the program will print "All letters entered are upper case" and the program will also count all the letters entered this number will also be displayed. I am really new to programming please have patience with me.

This is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
char myChar;

do
{
  myChar = getchar();
  printf("%02x ",myChar); // this is here to help debugging

  if(myChar == EOF) // if get user enters an EOF or the EOF is reached
     {
        printf("All are caps\n");
        // print  number of letters entered 
        // break out of loop and end program  
     }   

}
while(((myChar&0x20) == 0)); 
{
      printf("\n");
      printf("entered LOWER CASE = %c \n",myChar);
      printf("The hex value is = %x \n",myChar); // hex value of lower case letter

}
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which bit are you having difficulty with? What is your input, what output are you getting, and what output were you expecting?

Comment: `myChar` needs to be `int`, not `char`, otherwise you won't be able to reliably detect `EOF`.

Comment: Some observations: `getchar()` return `int`, `EOF` is *not* a `char`, and you shall use `islower()` to check for lower case.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void){
    int myChar;
    int allCaps = 1;
    int count = 0;

    while(EOF!=(myChar = getchar())){
        if(isupper(myChar)){
            ++count;
        } else {
            if(islower(myChar)){
                printf("entered LOWER CASE = %c\n", myChar);
                printf("The hex value is = %02x\n", myChar);
            } else if(myChar == '\n'){
                continue;
            }
            allCaps = 0;
        }
    }
    if(allCaps){
        printf("All letters entered are upper case\n");
        printf("number of letters entered : %d\n", count);
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```